# Using gravity with Compound TextView with drawable creates space

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got 2 Compound TextViews inside a horizontal `LinearLayout`. Each `TextView` has equal weight, so its spaced out evenly. I then set gravity on each of the TextViews to center everything inside its allotted space, but this causes the drawable to not move, and not center with the text. Image to clarify: http://prntscr.com/9mnpwn

Here is my current code:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1"
             >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/numComments"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_chat_24dp"
                android:text="9"
                android:layout_gravity="center"

                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="#99ff0000"

                />
            <TextView

                android:background="#9900ff00"
                android:id="@+id/submitTime"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_schedule_24dp"
                android:text="3 hours ago"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".5"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

I usually do this with nested LinearLayouts containing a textview and imageview for the icon, but obviously using these compound TextViews is cleaner. Any ideas how to get this working and centered properly?

Comment: how a drawableLeft can come to center??

Comment: @VivekMishra yes im trying to center everything.

Comment: it will not as it is left aligned. To do it you have to separate both of them

Comment: or one thing you can try . Add padding left to the textview

Comment: @VivekMishra Yea, i can add padding to the left and then do negative padding on `drawablePadding`. This kinda works but if possible i would like a more intuitive solution.

Comment: then you have to create imageview and textview separately